# When should the parameters of operator overloading functions be passed by constant reference?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

The lhs and rhs are passed by constant reference (const Type&).

```
CVector operator+ (const CVector& lhs, const CVector& rhs) {
    CVector temp;
    temp.x = lhs.x + rhs.x;
    temp.y = lhs.y + rhs.y;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You have better chances of getting an answer if you tag the question with the language you are using.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, i.e is it wrt using const? or using reference? Do you wish to know which is preferred when (pass by value, pointer, ref)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When it is lightweight(cheap) data  to copy (e.g. for ints, float ,char  etc. passing by value is just fine)
2. The parameter is observed in the function/operator implementation (i.e. it's an input read-only parameter)

as a sum up of both points you will get we will get why we should pass by constant reference.

For clear understanding see http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/references.html

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to follow these guidelines for choosing how to take parameters. For input-only parameters:

- Always const-qualify all pointers or references to input-only parameters.
- Prefer taking inputs of primitive types (e.g., char, float) and value objects that are cheap to copy (e.g., Point, complex) by value.
- Prefer taking inputs of other user-defined types by reference to const.
- Consider pass-by-value instead of reference if the function requires a copy of its argument. This is conceptually identical to taking a reference to const plus doing a copy, and it can help compiler to better optimize away temporaries.

For output or input/output parameters:

- Prefer passing by (smart) pointer if the argument is optional (so callers can pass null as a "not available" or "don't care" value) or if the function stores a copy of the pointer or otherwise manipulates ownership of the argument.
- Prefer passing by reference if the argument is required and the function won't store a pointer to it or otherwise affect its ownership. This states that the argument is required and makes the caller responsible for providing a valid object.

Reference: [C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices] #25. Take parameters appropriately by value, (smart) pointer, or reference

Answer (score 0):

In few words, to ensure immutability of data. 
Excerpts from the link below:

> When an argument is passed by reference, a reference is created to the actual argument (which takes minimal time) and no copying of values takes place. This allows us to pass large structs and classes with a minimum performance penalty.
>   References allow the function to change the value of the argument, which in many cases is undesirable. If we know that a function should not change the value of an argument, but don’t want to pass by value, the best solution is to pass by const reference. 
>   A `const` reference is a reference that does not allow the variable being referenced to be changed. Consequently, if we use a const reference as a parameter, we guarantee to the caller that the function will not (and can not) change the argument!

Ref: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/

Comment: I think he means to compare between *const reference* and *by value* - in both cases the original data is immutable

Comment: All answers seems to point to it. Question seems ambiguous. I will post a remark to clarify the same.

Answer (score 0):

`why arguments are passed as constant` 
=> when one wants to prevent respective data members from being altered in the called function.

`why constant references`
=> to Prevent the creation of temporary objects